# Replace column values in table with values from lookup based on matches in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lookup

I'd like to replace values in the **table** column with corresponding values of matches in the **lookup** column. I achieved this with data.table package "assign by reference" taking one value (and it's replacement) after the other, but I thought I could do something more modular.

In summary, I do this:

```
# Build a table and a lookup
code<- c("ABC","EBC","ABC","EBC","OOO","PPP","ABC")
sn <- c(1:7)
old<- c("ABC","EBC")
new<- c("CBa","CBe")

lookup <- data.frame(old,new)
table <-data.frame(code,sn)

# Set data.table as TRUE for both
setDT(table)
setDT(lookup)

# Attempt reassignment
table[code %in% lookup$old, code := lookup$new[which(lookup$old==code)]]
table
```

..and I get this:

```
> table
   code sn
1:  CBa  1
2:  CBe  2
3: <NA>  3
4: <NA>  4
5:  OOO  5
6:  PPP  6
7: <NA>  7
```

However, what I really hope for is this results:

```
> table
   code sn
1:  CBa  1
2:  CBe  2
3:  CBa  3
4:  CBe  4
5:  OOO  5
6:  PPP  6
7:  CBa  7
```

In essence: the replacement is made based on the lookup with all values assigned (not just the first two). What am I missing? I have tried looking for other solutions around but suggestions don't quite seem to be what I am looking for. Grateful for any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do a join `on` the 'code' and 'old' from table and lookup respectively

```
table[lookup, code := new, on = .(code = old)]
```

-output

```
 table
   code sn
1:  CBa  1
2:  CBe  2
3:  CBa  3
4:  CBe  4
5:  OOO  5
6:  PPP  6
7:  CBa  7
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option can work (but highly recommend [@akrun's `data.table` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67908770/12158757), super elegant!)

```
transform(
  table,
  code = replace(
    code,
    code %in% lookup$old,
    setNames(lookup$new, lookup$old)[code][code %in% lookup$old]
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   code sn
1:  CBa  1
2:  CBe  2
3:  CBa  3
4:  CBe  4
5:  OOO  5
6:  PPP  6
7:  CBa  7
```

---

Or a longer `data.table` option

```
> lookup[table, on = .(old = code)][, new := fcoalesce(new, old)][, old := NULL][]
   new sn
1: CBa  1
2: CBe  2
3: CBa  3
4: CBe  4
5: OOO  5
6: PPP  6
7: CBa  7
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all your contributions (@akrun: wow! @ThomasIsCoding: learned something new with the base solution - thank you.